# What's the meaning of `VCP` and `VFP`?

Tags: virtualbox, vmware

when I read [vMX blog](http://matt.dinham.net/juniper-vmx-getting-started-guide-vmware/).

there are bellow list:

> Software image for vMX VCP: jinstall64-vmx-15.1F4.15-domestic.vmdk
>   Software image for VCP file storage: vmxhdd.vmdk
>   Software image for VFP: vFPC-20151203.vmdk
>   metadata_usb.vmdk: Virtual hard disk with bootstrapping information. This is used by the VCP.

I want to know what's the meaning of `VCP` and `VFP`.
is it related to virtual technology?

Comment: This might help: https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/vmx14.1/topics/concept/vmx-architecture.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know VCP stand for Virtual Control Plane and VFP for Virtual Forwarding Plane, they are related to virtual network technology. In this case loosely speaking "subsystems" to the Juniper vMX Virtual Router (both are virtual machines "VM"s).

[Kinnectus](https://superuser.com/users/321172/kinnectus) put a [link](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/vmx14.1/topics/concept/vmx-architecture.html) in the comments is actually gives a pretty good explanation...  should have looked at it before I wrote the answer...